# What is the word on this vehicle?

Tags: german-to-english

Any ideas, I'm guess about 1940

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Do you just have the digital version of this picture or do have the physical copy? In the latter case - is there anything written on the back?

Comment: just the digital photos

Comment: I'm thinking that it could be a truncated girl's name, e.g. Sadee, Sadella, Sadelle, Sadellia, Sadie, Sadye, Saidee etc...

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 Those names were not very common in Germany of that time, though.

Comment: Possible, but unlikely: "Südtiroler Ordnungsdienst" - a paramilitarian organisation in South Tirol. Vehicle does, however, look like a regular Wermacht SdKfz. 221.

Comment: I read it as "Sod.", with the dot likely meaning it's an abbreviation. Could be anything, the beginning of the name of the commanding officer, a place, a nickname.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to ask this at [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/) - they might know, whether there were typical inscriptions on vehicles, or they know which terms/names were abbreviated 'Sad./Sod.'

Comment: It may be one, but it is unclear if it is a meaningful writing at all. It is blurry, partly cut off or painted over and that's where the brain starts to search for similarities ...

Comment: In case that helps, that armoured vehicle is a Sd.Kfz. 221.

Comment: @tofro The license plate says "WH" which is Wehrmacht, Heer (the Army). See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_deutschen_Kfz-Kennzeichen_(historisch)#Deutsches_Reich_1933_bis_1945

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not determinable. There is no such troop unit sign or tactical sign of the Wehrmacht<sup>[[1]](http://www.wehrmacht-lexikon.de/heer/einheiten/zusatzmaterial/kraftfahrzeuge/truppenteil.php)</sup><sup>[[2]](http://www.wehrmacht-lexikon.de/heer/einheiten/zusatzmaterial/kraftfahrzeuge/taktische.php)</sup>, also not for this special Sd.Kfz. 221<sup>[[3]](http://www.wehrmacht-lexikon.de/heer/waffen/waffentechnik/panzerfahrzeuge/panzerspaehwagen/index.php)</sup>. There is no such abbreviation in the official information office about the Wehrmacht<sup>[[4]](https://www.bundesarchiv.de/DE/Content/Downloads/Aus-unserer-Arbeit/abkuerzungsverzeichnis-wast.pdf?__blob=publicationFile)</sup>, either.

That's why most likely it's a sign of barracks this vehicle came from, or a sign of the responsible soldier or something. Anyway it seems it's not an official abbreviation. Maybe it abbreviates the town or village where they are coming from, but one does not have a fast clue which one this could be.

I also searched Google Pictures for photographs of that Panzerspähwagen but all available vehicles of this type don't have a similar sign, especially at this place on the tank.